# How to use function's return within other function (without using class)

Tags: python, django

I have a function:

```
def search_result(request):

    if request.method =='POST':
        data = request.body
        qd = QueryDict(data)
        place = qd.values()[2]
        indate = qd.values()[3]
        outdate = qd.values()[0]
        url = ('http://terminal2.expedia.com/x/mhotels/search?city=%s&checkInDate=%s&checkOutDate=%s&room1=2&apikey=%s') %(place, indate, outdate, MY_API_KEY)
        req = requests.get(url).text
        json_data = json.loads(req)

        results = []
        for hotels in json_data.get('hotelList'):
            results.append(hotels.get('localizedName'))
        return HttpResponse(results)
```

now I want to use func1's return within other function to render template something like this:

```
def search_page(request):

    r = search_result(request)
    d = r.content
    return render(request,'search.html', {'res':d})
```

and this actually do not work.
Does any way exist to do  what I want (without using class)? 
I make post via ajax from template form and my first function works properly and prints result in console. The problems occurs when I try use my response in next function to render it in template. Thats why I ask to help me. Have you any ideas to make my response from first function visible for another function?

Comment: I don't see any reason why the code should not work

Comment: It fails with error "func1() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)"

Comment: Ah ok, yep, I missed the request, well bar you make request a global or you can pass it to the function then you don't have much choice bar using attributes

Comment: I didn't fully realize what you meant, could you please write it down?

Comment: func1 takes a request args, unless the request in func2 is also the same request then you would have to somehow declare it globally so it is accessible in func2 but global is pretty much always a bad idea. The second option of taking a second arg in func which is the request would most like break your code bar you restructured it to take two arguments in your django logic

Comment: I know global variable is generally a bad idea. What about second option, I do not understand what you exactly meant.

Comment: @Padraic please don't suggest things like that. Making the request global will immediately lead to horrible thread safety issues.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, I was not suggesting it, *but global is pretty much always a bad idea.*

Answer (score 0):

You have defined `func1` to take the `request` parameter, but when you call it in your second function you do not pass it any arguments.

If you pass in `request` it should work.

EDIT: You are looking for the results, so I suppose you can just return them instead of the `HttpResponse` (maybe we need more information on what you are trying to accomplish)

```
def func1(request): 
    ......
    results = []
    for hotels in json_data.get('hotelList'):
        results.append(hotels.get('localizedName'))

    return results


def funk2(request):

    f = funk1(request)

    return render(request,'search.html', {'res':f})
```

Comment: `d = f.results` will raise an `AttributeError` beacause `f` is an instance of `HttpResponse` and it doesn't have any attribute called `results`.

Comment: @Barnabus, thanks but "NoneType' object has no attribute 'results'"

Comment: @xyres, seems i understand it but how to change code to make working?

Comment: @AndriyKravchenko If you use `f = func1(request)` and `d = f.content`, your original code might work.

Comment: @xyres, what is 'content' here?

Comment: @AndriyKravchenko `content` is an attribute of `HttpResponse`. [See docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse.content).

Comment: but 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'content'

Comment: @AndriyKravchenko In your original code `func1` is returning `HttpResponse`. I don't see why it's actually returning `None`. Is that all of your `func1`  code?

Comment: @AndriyKravchenko what @xyres is saying is accurate (I don't work with HttpResponse, so if my answer was misleading I apologise). HttpResponse returns an object with an attribute `content` that is a bytestring of whatever you passed in. Only thing to bear in mind is [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#passing-iterators): you're passing in a list, which will be converted to a string. If you want it as a list still you need to return it.

Comment: @xyres,@Barnabus, it is my whole actual code.I checked again, HttpResponse really exists, I can print it but .content still don't work 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'content' . Maybe  `f = func1(request)` do not get actual request?

Comment: @AndriyKravchenko It isn't your whole code as you have omitted the first few lines of `func1`. Maybe edit your question to include the whole function, it will make it easier to see what is wrong with your code.

Comment: @AndriyKravchenko `func1` only returns `HttpResponse` object if a post request is made. Otherwise it will just return `None`. Which is what's happening here.

Comment: I make post via ajax from template form and my first function works properly and prints result in console. The problems occurs when I try use my response in next function to render it in template. Thats why I ask to help me. Have you any ideas to make my response from first function visible for another function?